# Install4j OS X - moving a file from an application bundle

Tags: install4j

I am using an installer to upgrade an existing app.  In the old version of the app, the config was stored in the application bundle in the sys.contentDir directory.  In the new version of the app we are moving the config to the ~/Library/`AppName`/ directory.  A default config ships with the installer.  After installing the files I have a `Move Action` that should take the config if there is one in the user's `sys.contentDir` and move it and overwrite the one in ~/Library/`AppName` directory that the installer installed with the `Install Files` step.  Nothing happens and the only error message I get is that the step finished unsuccessfully.  I have tried forcing the installer to run as root and even moving the file to /tmp instead as a test.  I have set `Overwrite Mode` to `Always Ask`, but it never asks.  I also tried copying it and nothing is working.  Any insight as to where I can find a detailed error message or what might be going on is greatly appreciated.  From my steps it seems that there may be a permissions error accessing the config in the installation directory but I am running the installer as myself and I have permission to that file.

Log file output for the Copy and Move Actions:

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.CopyFileAction: Before execute action                                                                                            
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.CopyFileAction: Property shared: false                                                                                           
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.CopyFileAction: Property mode: 644                                                                                               
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.CopyFileAction: Property overwriteMode: Always ask except for update                                                             
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.CopyFileAction: Property uninst allMode: If created                                                                              
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.CopyFileAction: Property destin ationFile: /Users/brian/Library/DesktopClient/copy.xml                                           
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.CopyFileAction: Property delay: false                                                                                            
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.CopyFileAction: Property triggerReboot: true                                                                                     
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.CopyFileAction: Property directoryMode: 755                                                                                      
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.CopyFileAction: Property sourceFile: /Applications/DesktopClient.app/Contents/Resources/app/desktop-client.xml                   
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.CopyFileAction: Property rollbackSupported: true                                                                                 
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.CopyFileAction: Execute action not successful                                                                                   
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.MoveFileAction: Before execute action                                                                                            
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.MoveFileAction: Property shared : false                                                                                          
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.MoveFileAction: Property mode: 644                                                                                               
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.MoveFileAction: Property overwriteMode: Always ask                                                                               
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.MoveFileAction: Property uninstallMode: Always                                                                                   
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.MoveFileAction: Property destinationFile: /Users/brian/Library/DesktopClient/move.xml                                            
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.MoveFileAction: Property delay: false                                                                                            
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.MoveFileAction: Property triggerReboot: true                                                                                     
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.MoveFileAction: Property directoryMode: 755                                                                                      
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.MoveFileAction: Property sourceFile: /Applications/DesktopClient.app/Contents/Resources/app/desktop-client.xml                   
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.MoveFileAction: Property rollbackSupported: true                                                                                 
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.MoveFileAction: Execute action not successful
```

Comment: What is the output in the .install4/installation.log file after the installation?

Comment: I have added the log output for the two actions.  I figured the whole log might be a bit much but I can make it available to you if needed.

Comment: I assume both source file and target directory exist. What version of install4j do you use? In recent versions there should be an additional line that explains the reason for the failure.

Comment: Yes, the source file and target directory do exist.  The target directory is created by the previous step which installs the files.  It creates the ~/Library/DesktopClient dir when it places the default configuration file in it.  The version I am using is 4.2.8.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: OK, unfortunately I can only diagnose this for the current version. Can you try it with 5.1.3? If the problem is the same, it will print a diagnostic message.

Comment: Thanks.  The issue was that I had a space at the end of the file path.  I was able to see this because in 5.1.3 the quotes around the source file showed the space.  That and the error message that the file did not exist.  Thanks for the info on this.  I'd like to have my company upgrade to the new version but I'm not sure we use it often enough to justify the upgrade price for a floating license.  Thanks again for the help.  If you post an answer with information from your comment then I will give you credit for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of install4j (5.1.3) will print a diagnostic message that shows why the action fails. In 4.2.8 no diagnostic information is written to the log file.